# Create Durable Azure function using .NET 6

Tags: .net-6.0

Follow the steps mentioned in Microsoft documentation as mentioned here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-create-first-csharp?pivots=code-editor-visualstudio

After function creation, if you face errors, make sure the following settings/configurations are there as mentioned in the below answer

Answer (score 0):

Perform the below actions or verify with the below steps

- You must add the package microsoft.azure.webjobs.extensions.storage latest version
- Update your existing package versions to the latest specially
- microsoft.azure.webjobs.extensions.durabletask\2.7.2\
- nmicrosoft.net.sdk.functions\4.1.1\

Good to include the following in your local.setting.json

- "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
- "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
- "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"

Modify csproj project file to make sure your azure function has the following

- TargetFramework as net6.0
- AzureFunctionsVersion as v4

Your JSON configuration file must have
"FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION" as "~4"

Make sure Azurite is up and coming

- Close add visual studio instances
- open cmd with administrator rights
- Navigate to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Azure Storage Emulator
- type "azurite.exe" and press enter

Note: Always run azurite first and then open visual studio

The above step will help you to make sure azurite is running perfectly without error especially
azure storage emulator error **"Port conflict with an existing application"**